# "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: nginx, debian

Раньше NGinx работал нормально, теперь такая ошибка:

```
nginx: [error] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Часть nginx.conf:

```
user debian;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
```

Раньше всё работало, что с ним случилось?

---

из комментариев:

```
$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] open() "/home/user/logs/nginx.access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: `sudo nginx -t` проведет анализ конфигов и скажет вам, что ему не нравится (если причина в конфиге, конечно).

Comment: 
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] open() "/home/user/logs/nginx.access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed


Ну видимо ему не нравится то что нельзя открыть лог. Что делать?

Главная проблема в том что он не может найти nginx.pid,хотя раньше всё работало!

Comment: @ASaCe,

1. То, что не может найти nginx.pid - это не главная проблема, это ее последствия в виде того, что nginx не смог стартовать. В .pid-файлах хранят просто идентификатор процесса, не более.
2. Для nginx невозможность открыть лог является фатальной ошибкой. Он действительно не может достучаться до файла, и поэтому отказывается стартовать. Для возвращения к нормальной жизни надо либо создать эту папку с необходимыми разрешения доступа, либо в конфиге поправить расположение лога.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. У меня остался последний вопрос - почему он ищет этот файл в папке /home/user, когда надо искать в папке /home/debian?

В конфигах указана директория /home/debian и пользователь debian.

Comment: скинь конфиг nginx, тогда понятнее будет.

Comment: @ASaCe, он ищет *в том числе* и этот лог, вполне возможно, что /home/debian он нашел, а /home/user указан в одном из хостов.

Answer (score 5):

ответ из комментария:

1. То, что не может найти nginx.pid - это не главная проблема, это ее последствия в виде того, что nginx не смог стартовать. В .pid-файлах хранят просто идентификатор процесса, не более.
2. Для nginx невозможность открыть лог является фатальной ошибкой. Он действительно не может достучаться до файла, и поэтому отказывается стартовать. Для возвращения к нормальной жизни надо либо создать эту папку с необходимыми разрешения доступа, либо в конфиге поправить расположение лога.

Answer (score 2):

проверьте запущен ли nginx

```
sudo service nginx status
```

Если не запущен

```
sudo service nginx start
```

Команда для проверки конфигурации

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Answer (score 2):

Мне помогло:

```
$ nginx -c /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
sudo nginx -s quit
sudo nginx
sudo nginx -s reopen
sudo nginx -s reload
```